# Repeated updates

Tags: updates, update-manager, mesa

I am getting the same Ubuntu base and mesa updates every day. I have installed these same ones more than 10 times now and each day it shows me the same updates that need to be installed. I have no idea what's causing the issue, and similarly I do not know what data I need to provide to find a solution.

[image: The updates]

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                                  
Hit:4 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease                               
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                  
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                            
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                 
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy InRelease [23.9 kB]                                    
Hit:10 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org groovy InRelease                                    
Fetched 23.9 kB in 2s (12.1 kB/s)                         
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade --dry-run**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Input commands after an update was available:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                                                                        
Hit:3 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                                                                      
Hit:4 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                                                       
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                
Get:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease [6,259 B]                                                                  
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                   
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:10 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org groovy InRelease        
Get:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy/main Sources [2,416 B]
Get:12 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy/main i386 Packages [11.4 kB]
Get:12 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy/main i386 Packages [11.4 kB]
Err:12 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy/main i386 Packages
  File has unexpected size (8364 != 11408). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 151.101.10.217 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:11408 [weak]
   - SHA512:0e20248f05259b4d3ead9506673eddf9718c92ff000274a944c278c58d8824d0702c1d31e71cb2eaacf6753b9900b1ef93bc6f969f8d85403f78e9ddccd478f9
   - SHA256:ef16c559a95c24229d151011d21379757819eedca7dc823c0149858bf0bc90fc
   - SHA1:883e373057f2e8cbaef410a8ba8b6180632d4496 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:53d09c898744d076aa509e04fb92aca2 [weak]
  Release file created at: Sat, 07 Nov 2020 15:59:19 +0000
Reading package lists... Done  
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/groovy/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz  File has unexpected size (8364 != 11408). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 151.101.10.217 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:11408 [weak]
    - SHA512:0e20248f05259b4d3ead9506673eddf9718c92ff000274a944c278c58d8824d0702c1d31e71cb2eaacf6753b9900b1ef93bc6f969f8d85403f78e9ddccd478f9
    - SHA256:ef16c559a95c24229d151011d21379757819eedca7dc823c0149858bf0bc90fc
    - SHA1:883e373057f2e8cbaef410a8ba8b6180632d4496 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:53d09c898744d076aa509e04fb92aca2 [weak]
   Release file created at: Sat, 07 Nov 2020 15:59:19 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers
  mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
19 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 44.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libegl-mesa0 amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [141 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 libgbm1 i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [73.3 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libgbm1 amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [72.2 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [10.1 MB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [10.1 MB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libosmesa6 amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [2,875 kB]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 libosmesa6 i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [2,888 kB] 
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libglx-mesa0 amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [189 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 libglx-mesa0 i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [197 kB] 
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 libglapi-mesa i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [71.2 kB]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libglapi-mesa amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [71.1 kB]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [50.6 kB]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 libgl1-mesa-glx i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [50.6 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 mesa-va-drivers i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [2,755 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 mesa-va-drivers amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [2,668 kB]
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [2,884 kB]
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 mesa-vdpau-drivers amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [2,797 kB]
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers i386 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [3,366 kB]
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 mesa-vulkan-drivers amd64 20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g [3,362 kB]
Fetched 44.7 MB in 4min 10s (179 kB/s)                                                                                                     
(Reading database ... 212550 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libegl-mesa0_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl-mesa0:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libgbm1_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libgbm1:i386 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking libgbm1:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgbm1_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libgl1-mesa-dri_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libgl1-mesa-dri_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libosmesa6_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libosmesa6:amd64 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking libosmesa6:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libosmesa6_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libglx-mesa0_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libglx-mesa0_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libglapi-mesa_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libglapi-mesa:i386 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libglapi-mesa_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-libgl1-mesa-glx_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libgl1-mesa-glx_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-mesa-va-drivers_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
De-configuring mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking mesa-va-drivers:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-mesa-va-drivers_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-mesa-vdpau-drivers_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
De-configuring mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-mesa-vdpau-drivers_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-mesa-vulkan-drivers_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_i386.deb ...
De-configuring mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Unpacking mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-mesa-vulkan-drivers_20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libgbm1:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libgbm1:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up mesa-va-drivers:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libosmesa6:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libosmesa6:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libegl-mesa0:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.32-0ubuntu3) ...
```

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Copy the complete output of both out of the terminal and [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1290242/edit) above. Both outputs must be complete -- summaries are not helpful.

Comment: If it's the same (identical) updates, I'd perform the update via terminal so messages are shown on screen. If you use the GUI tool, you may need to search in logs to find issues/problems and then correct.  This is an installed system isn't it?  (not a *live* system)

Comment: @guiverc Ok I'll try to update it from the terminal next time the update window pops up with the identical updates. And yes its not a live system.

Comment: "*All packages are up to date.*" That's good. Repeat the process when they are not up to date. That will allow us to compare packages and see error messages.

Comment: @user535733 yup will do, if things go as they do it should appear tomorrow this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ubuntu Base" is actually just a short name that refers to a LOT of libs and programs.  If you expand that you'll see different libs each time.

The regular updates **ARE NORMAL** to have because of bugfixes and updates getting in, whether security or not, and it is **not unusual** to have those show daily with new updates.

And as an example, you can see that many of these 'packages' here are **different versions**.  You can tell that from the strings:

```
Unpacking mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.3~git2011070730.b7793e~oibaf~g) over (20.3~git2011061930.a0b42d~oibaf~g) ...
```

You're using the oibaf PPA/drivers repository which takes **nightly git snapshots** from Upstream repositories and publishes new packages - because you're pulling those in from a third party repository (see this line: `Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu groovy InRelease`) you are at the mercy of that repository.

The standard Ubuntu repositories do not get those packages updated nightly.  Third party package repositories (such as the OIBAF one and the graphics-drivers PPA and the WineHQ PPA) will **always** provide updates in different cycles and schedules so you are always going to be getting updates because of nightly builds happening (hence why you see those showing up every day).

Comment: I get the same updates, they have the same name, they take the same amount of storage and everything. Its not new updates, its just the same ones getting reinstalled over and over again.

Comment: @AmberB. the *sizes* of the packages and name are likely to be the same.  Run this on the command line: `sudo apt dist-upgrade --dry-run`.  Copy and paste **all the output** into your question as an edit.

Comment: done, I ran the command just after I updated the same updates again using commands this time. I edited the output.

Comment: @AmberB. you have third party repositories in play - the `graphics-drivers` PPA and the `oibaf` PPAs - the oibaf ones update nightly, and will ALWAYS have new updates daily for you, so that's why you're getting **the same updated packages regularly** - third party repositories are always likely to get more updates than the standard repos, especially the OIBAF ones which do nightly git snapshot builds.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks!